# Ring homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb Z_{(p)}\to\mathbb F_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for a ring homomorphism  $$\varphi: \mathbb Z_{(p)}\to\mathbb F_p$$ with kernel $(p)$. I have tried mapping $\frac{a}{b}$ to $a+p\mathbb Z$ or $ab+p\mathbb Z$ but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

I suppose  $\mathbf Z_{(p)}$ denotes the localisation at the prime ideal $p\mathbf Z$.

Map $\mathbf Z_{(p)}$ onto its residue field $\;\mathbf Z_{(p)}/p\mathbf Z_{(p)}$ by the canonical map .

**Other method** (depending on what you assume to be known):

Observe the canonical map $\mathbf Z\longrightarrow\mathbf F_p, \; n\longmapsto n+p\mathbf Z$, maps  the multiplicative set $S=\mathbf Z-p\mathbf Z$ onto $\mathbf F_p^\times$, so by the universal property of rings of fractions, it factors through $S^{-1}\mathbf Z=\mathbf Z_{(p)}$.

Comment: Well, in the end I want something like $\mathbb Z_{(p)}/(p)\cong\mathbb F_p$ which I wanted to show via the homomorphism theorem. So using the canonical map just puts my problem somewhere else.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to prove what I consider a basic result?

Comment: Yes, if you consider $\mathbb Z_{(p)}/(p)\cong\mathbb F_p$ basic - this is what I was trying to show here in the first place.

Comment: OK. I've posted another hint. what's basic  is that (in a general context) if $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of a ring $R$, $\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p}$ is maximal ideal of $R_{\mathfrak p}$, and its residue field is but the field of fractions of the quotient $R/\mathfrak p$. Add to this the fact that in $\mathbf Z$, non-zero prime ideals are maximal.

Comment: Just as a side question: Is it possible to explicitly write down what the homomorphism does? Something like $\varphi(\frac{a}{b})=\dots$? That would be interesting to know.

Comment: Yes, though it's not very explicit: as $b$ is  invertible mod. $p$ (inverse $b^{-1}$ found via a Bézout's relation between $b$ and $p$) you map $a/b$ to $\; ab^{-1}+p\mathbf Z$.